# How can I limit the results in a PagingAndSortingRepository @Query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

Frameworks: Spring 4.0.7 and Hibernate 4.3.6

We are having problems with a `PagingAndSortingRepository` `@Query` taking an excessive amount of time to complete as it appears to be running through recordset data and building structures before factoring in page data limits.

In non-joined scenarios, the `fetch first n rows` appears as it should, and the resultset is much smaller making the selection very snappy on the first batch of pages.

The initial problem we ran into was that we were unable to do a `@Query` with an `inner join fetch` (to force the join) on detail records.  Removing the fetch obviously gets us off the ground, but creates a nested SQL loop which is not desirable.

To get around this, we added `countQuery` which got us the proper count back, but now appears to load the entire structure in memory before returning the paged results.  Turning on debugging shows the records being loaded in.  The `fetch first n rows` has not been added.

Having nested SQLs running in a loop is not an option for us, so removing the fetch does not help.

```
@Query(value = "select e from InvoiceHistoryHeader e inner join fetch e.details f where e.company = ?1 and e.division = ?2 and e.customerNumber = ?3)", countQuery = "select count(e) from InvoiceHistoryHeader e where e.company = ?1 and e.division = ?2 and e.customerNumber = ?3)")
Page<InvoiceHistoryHeader> findByCustomerNumber(String company, String division, String customerNumber, Pageable pageable);
```

Can anyone provide a solution to this problem, or give a workaround that may help?  I can provide more detail as needed.

EDIT (11/11/2014)

Hibernate output (no fetch):

```
Hibernate: select count(trim(invoicehis0_.HH_TID)) as col_0_0_ from invhh invoicehis0_ where trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CO)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DIV)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CUS)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_BR)=?
Hibernate: select invoicehis0_.hh_tid as hh_tid1_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CO) as hh_co2_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CUS) as hh_cus3_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DTI) as hh_dti4_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DIV) as hh_div5_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_ORD) as hh_ord6_7_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_BR) as hh_br7_7_ from invhh invoicehis0_ where trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CO)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DIV)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CUS)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_BR)=? fetch first 20 rows only 
Hibernate: select details0_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_7_0_, trim(details0_.HD_SEQ) as hd_seq1_6_0_, trim(details0_.HD_TID) as hd_tid2_6_0_, details0_.hd_seq as hd_seq1_6_1_, details0_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_6_1_, trim(details0_.HD_DTL) as hd_dtl3_6_1_, trim(details0_.HD_LIN) as hd_lin4_6_1_ from invhd details0_ where details0_.hd_tid=?
Hibernate: select details0_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_7_0_, trim(details0_.HD_SEQ) as hd_seq1_6_0_, trim(details0_.HD_TID) as hd_tid2_6_0_, details0_.hd_seq as hd_seq1_6_1_, details0_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_6_1_, trim(details0_.HD_DTL) as hd_dtl3_6_1_, trim(details0_.HD_LIN) as hd_lin4_6_1_ from invhd details0_ where details0_.hd_tid=?
<above two SQL repeated 18 more times>
```

Hibernate output (fetch and countQuery):

```
Hibernate: select invoicehis0_.hh_tid as hh_tid1_7_0_, details1_.hd_seq as hd_seq1_6_1_, details1_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_6_1_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CO) as hh_co2_7_0_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CUS) as hh_cus3_7_0_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DTI) as hh_dti4_7_0_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DIV) as hh_div5_7_0_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_ORD) as hh_ord6_7_0_, trim(invoicehis0_.HH_BR) as hh_br7_7_0_, trim(details1_.HD_DTL) as hd_dtl3_6_1_, trim(details1_.HD_LIN) as hd_lin4_6_1_, details1_.hd_tid as hd_tid2_7_0__, trim(details1_.HD_SEQ) as hd_seq1_6_0__, trim(details1_.HD_TID) as hd_tid2_6_0__ from invhh invoicehis0_ inner join invhd details1_ on trim(invoicehis0_.HH_TID)=details1_.hd_tid where trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CO)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_DIV)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_CUS)=? and trim(invoicehis0_.HH_BR)=?
```

Comment: I've added what I believe you are looking for.  I can't output the plan for the fetch join as it won't run when it is contained in the  `@Query`.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke on that.  I've added both plans, first without the inner join fetch and the second with the fetch + countQuery that isn't limiting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using fetch in join and paging Hibernate does in-memory pagination, which means it loads all records in memory. 
Do not use fetch joins with paging.